# Authorize.net CIM Active Merchant -- User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, authorize.net, activemerchant

I have deployed my live app with working payment gateway but I still need somewhere to test so created a account with sandbox.authorize.net and got a new api key.

Now when I try these details in development/staging I get -

```
User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values
```

When accessing authorize.net

Does active merchant work with sandbox.authorize.net? testing seems to work fine with a gateway set in test mode but not with a sandbox account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this working with the following code:

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetCimGateway.new( 
  :login => login, 
  :password => password
)
```

Orginally my connector looked like this(as the api shows it):

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetCimGateway.new( 
  :login =>    login, 
  :password => password,
  :test        true
)
```

Comment: If using rails, you can also add ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test to config/environments/development.rb and config/environments/staging.rb which will automatically use the test attribute in those environments.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because test mode uses your live account's test mode and doesn't actually point to the development server for Authnet. I don't know how Active Merchant is written but it may require you changing the URL manually for testing and then returning its original value when testing is complete.